# Trigger another Jenkins job multiple times

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using a Jenkins 2.375.2 pipeline job I tried to create a job that batches another job. It takes a batch count and triggers the other job with parameters that many times. The other job queues itself with lockable resources. The goal is to batch up a user-specified number of runs of another job to go overnight/weekend for stability testing. I looked for a plugin that would let me do this directly to the other job but didn't find anything so I am trying this approach. The batch job runs fine and says it triggered the other job multiple times and completes without error. The issue is the other job only actually gets triggered and queued once. Any ideas on how to make the build calls work as intended (actually build a queue on the other job)?

Update 1 - the target job has `Do not allow concurrent builds` unchecked

```
parameters {
    text(name: 'BATCH_COUNT', defaultValue: '10', description: 'Batch count')
    ...
}

stage('batch') {
    steps {
        
        script {
            for (int i = 0; i < "${params.BATCH_COUNT}".toInteger(); i++) {
                build wait: false, job: 'otherjob', parameters: [
                    ...
                ]
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have enabled `Do not allow concurrent builds`, unless Jenkins sees the run as an unique run it will not queue additional Jobs. In order to trick Jenkins you need to change a parameter each time you trigger the Job, If you use the same parameters it will think it's the same Job. So introduce a new Parameter in the target JOb and maybe pass the Iterate count to that which will make it unique.

In the target Job

```
string(name: 'UniqueString', defaultValue: 'o', description: 'something')
```

In the Triggering Job.

```
for (int i = 0; i < "${params.BATCH_COUNT}".toInteger(); i++) {
       build wait: false, job: 'otherjob', parameters: [ string(name: 'UniqueString',value: "$i")
                    ...
           ]
}
```